# datatables gives error if not defined columns

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I'm following this guide: 
http://www.ahmed-samy.com/php-codeigniter-full-featrued-jquery-datatables-part-1/

Their script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#big_table').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/subscriber/datatable',
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayStart ": 20,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sProcessing": "<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/ajax-loader_dark.gif'>"
            },
            "fnInitComplete": function () {
                //oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
            },
            'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax
                ({
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'url': sSource,
                    'data': aoData,
                    'success': fnCallback
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my script:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var oTable = $('#ManageForms').dataTable({

                "bServerSide":true,
                "bProcessing":true,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                //"bFilter":true,
                "sServerMethod": "POST",
                "sAjaxSource": "{{base_url()}}admin/configurations/listForms_DT/",
                "iDisplayLength": 2,
               // "aLengthMenu": [[2, 25, 50, -1], [2, 25, 50, "All"]],
//                "sEcho": 1,
/*                "columns":[
                    {data:"FormName"},
                    {data:"FormPath"},
                    {data:"FormCIPath"},
                    { "data": null,
                        "defaultContent": "<button>Edit</button>",
                        "targets": -1
                    }
                ],*/
                'fnServerData'   : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback){
                    $.ajax ({
                        'dataType': 'json',
                        'type'    : 'POST',
                        'url'     : sSource,
                        'data'    : aoData,
                        'success' : fnCallback
                    }); //end of ajax
                }

            });
        } );
    </script>
```

In tutorial they are not using columns and there table is working fine even with the search, but if I don't use columns which I have commented out, i get this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=ManageForms - Requested unknown parameter
>   '0' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/4

If I do use the columns, datatables work fine but my search doesn't work.  Why is it important for me to use columns but in tutorial they have not?

Comment: did you even read http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4

Comment: @Rufinus
Thanks for reply sir. i just read it. still i dont get it. why my datatables cant get data, where as in the tutorial it gets data and works fine.

Comment: with columns: check your get-vars from the ajax request, the col-names will have changed. without column names they are just indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you generating the table?

```
$this->table->generate();
```

Also, to search (filter), you need to append:

```
fnSetFilteringDelay(700); //delay amount
```